# import then export es6 syntax

Tags: javascript, import, export, ecmascript-6

Basic ES6 import/export syntax question. For convenience, I have a single file that's importing a bunch of other files. Then, modules can just include that one file to get access to all the info, rather than have separate imports for each and every file.

Here's how it's set up:

core.js

```
import C from './constants'
import E from './events'
import L from './lang_en'
// ... etc.

// console.log() on C, E, L here all confirm that they're 
// available. They were exported from the constants.js, events.js files 
// like: `export default { C };`
```

Now here's what I'd like to be able to do
myFile.js

```
import { C, E, L } from './core';
```

The problem is the syntax in the core.js file: I've tried numerous variations on the es6 export syntax, but none of which allow the import line as shown in module.js. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm. I tried that, I still get `undefined` for those vars in myFile.js. Guess the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: EDIT: ahh... found it. It was a load order issue: circular reference going on. Thanks @FelixKling.